# Python Socket - ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, sockets, valueerror

I am having issues with the socket only recieving data, but not the address so I cannot send packets such as an acknowledgement to the original sender. I am implementing a go-back-N with a sender and receiver.
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./netster.py", line 128, in <module>
    main()
  File "./netster.py", line 120, in main
    run_server(args.host, int(args.port), udp=args.udp, rudp = args.rudp, filename=f) 
  File "./netster.py", line 27, in run_server
    rudp_gobackn_recv(port, kwargs['filename'])
  File "/Users/a3.py", line 352, in rudp_gobackn_recv
    data, client_address = serversocket.recv(1500)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here is the receiver side of things, a code snippet showing how I initalize the packet and receive the data.

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', port))
...
data, client_address = serversocket.recv(1500)
```

This is how I set up the sender socket:

```
clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server_address = (host, port)
```

Both the sender and receiver have the address and port as

```
('localhost', 1234)
```

1234 is an arbitrary port number.
Here is how I set up the packets to send, just in case it matters, and how I send it.

```
for x in range(len(window), window_size):
            data = file.read(data_size)
            if not data:
                end_bit = '1'
            decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
            packet = str(nextseqnum) + "@@" + str(end_bit) + "@@" + str(decoded_data)
            nextseqnum = str(int(nextseqnum) + 1)
            window.append(packet)
            if not data:
                break
```

Here is how I send it:

```
for y in range(0, len(window)):
            print("Window: ", window)
            print("PACKET!!!!", window[y])
            packet = window[y]
            p = packet.encode('utf-8')
            print("Socket ouput: ", clientsocket.sendto(p, server_address))
            if(y == 0):
                oldest_time = time.time()
```

If I change the receiver code so it can compile to this:

```
data  = serversocket.recv(1500)
```

The sender side of things prints out:

```
Window:  ['1@@0@@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n', '2@@1@@']
PACKET!!!! 1@@0@@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Socket ouput:  33
Window:  ['1@@0@@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\n', '2@@1@@']
PACKET!!!! 2@@1@@
Socket ouput:  6
```

Any thoughts on why it sends only the data, but not the server address? I've researched the issue but have had no success, as well as debugging it for awhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serversocket.recv(1500)` only returns bytes, not `data, client_address`. You're looking for `recvfrom`.

And this should enlighten you as to why you get the error you do:

```
>>> data, client_address = b"hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>>> a, b, c, d, e = b"hello"
>>> a, b, c, d, e
(104, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```